# AWS dotnet deploy using aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json file - Visual Studio for MAC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-serverless

I have aws serverless application with two different template file. 
Now I need to know the command to deploy from Visual Studio for MAC using aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json file.

Tried using `dotnet lambda deploy-serverless -ts aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json`

But it shows error like this-
[image]

This is my aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json file
[image]

**NOTE - This file and config work very well in Visual Studio on Windows with AWS SDK**

Answer (score 0):

This terminal command works-

```
 dotnet lambda deploy-serverless aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json --profile {Credential Profile Name} -sn {Lambda Stack Name}
```